# Android Eclipse I tried all the solutions and still nothing

Tags: eclipse

I tried everything I could on the Android Eclipse.

The delete of virtual device and the moving around of the Android programs into C:

The only thing I noticed that in the Android folder itself I saw in the solutions that I don't have a Android/Android-SDK so that might be the problem.  But I know that I have downloaded that program from the Android developer site.

Any solutions?

This is in regards to the conflict with my Eclipse program:

```
[2011-07-16 17:58:38 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-07-16 17:58:38 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-16 17:58:38 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already downloaded the Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
and the ADT plugin for Eclipse (http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) -

In Eclipse, go to the Windows->Preferences menu and select **Android**. Set the SDK Location to where you installed the SDK and choose the platform/API level you want.